# Help needed on laurent series for a complex function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm struggling to understand the ways in which one could find the laurent series and there for the residuals for:

> Find the Laurent series expansion and residue at 
>   $$
> \left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^2
> $$
>   for $z = 1$

Any help that could be provided as to where to start would be appreciated. I attempted differentiating the Laurent series expansion for

$$
\frac{1}{z-1}
$$

Aswell as trying to multiply out the coefficients of the Laurent expansion for

$$
\frac{1}{z-1}
$$

But have had no luck whatsoever and just get myself into a state.

Answer (score 2):

Laurent series about $z=1$: 
$$ \begin{align}\frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2} &=\frac{z^2\color{blue}{-2z+2+2z-2}}{(z-1)^2} =\frac{\left(z^2-2z+1\right)+2\left(z-1\right)+1}{(z-1)^2} \\[2mm] &=\frac{(z-1)^2+2\left(z-1\right)+1}{(z-1)^2} =\color{red}{1+\frac{2}{z-1}+\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}} \end{align} $$ 
Taylor series at $z=0$: 
$$ \begin{align} \frac{z^2}{(z-1)^2} &=z^2\,\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)' =z^2\,\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n\right)' =z^2\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(z^n\right)' \\[2mm] &=z^2\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\,z^{n-1} =\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\,z^{n+1}} \end{align} $$

Comment: I don't understand what to do :s

Comment: Thank you for your help, but where you have expanded the taylor series at $z=0$ how would you find the residue?

Comment: @SebastianTG: Using Laurent series, the residue is the coefficient of $\,(z-1)^{-1}\,$, which is $\,2\,$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that
$$
\left( \frac{z}{z-1}\right)^2=\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1} \right)^2
$$

Comment: My confusion comes with dealing with the power of 2. Can I deal with the power series on its own within the brackets and then square the resulting laurent series